# what is the better solution for Performance counter Error on application Insights?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, logging, azure-application-insights

AI: Error collecting 3 of the configured performance counters. Please check the configuration.
Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests/Sec: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests/Sec, instance example.exe
Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Request Execution Time: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Request Execution Time, instance example.exe
Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests In Application Queue: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests In Application Queue, instance example.exe

Answer (score 2):

Probably those counters are not available on the platform or hosting option of your app.

**For .Net Core**

You can disable collecting them at all like this:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
            {
                options.EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule = false;
            });
            ...
        }
```

or you can remove (or add) counters like this:

```cs
        public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            ...
            var modules = app.ApplicationServices.GetServices<ITelemetryModule>();
            var perfModule = modules.OfType<PerformanceCollectorModule>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (perfModule != null)
            {
                perfModule.DefaultCounters.Remove(perfModule.DefaultCounters.First(dc =>
                    dc.PerformanceCounter == @"somecounter"));
            }
            ...
        }
```

**For Asp.Net**

Edit your `applicationinsights.config` file and remove the counters that give errors / you don't want:

```xml
<TelemetryModules>
    ...
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
        <DefaultCounters/>
        <Counters>
            <!--<Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time" />
                <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time Normalized" ReportAs="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time Normalized" /> -->
            <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Private Bytes" ReportAs="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Private Bytes" />
            <Add PerformanceCounter="\Memory\Available Bytes" ReportAs="\Memory\Available Bytes" />
            <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\IO Data Bytes/sec" ReportAs="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\IO Data Bytes/sec" />
            <Add PerformanceCounter="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" />
        </Counters>
    </Add>
    ...
</TelemetryModules>
```